# Unzip the archive with more than one entry

Tags: pipe, zip

I'm trying to decompress ~8GB `.zip` file piped from `curl` command. Everything I have tried is being interrupted at <1GB and returns a message:

> ... has more than one entry--rest ignored

I've tried: `funzip`, `gunzip`, `gzip -d`, `zcat`, ... also with different arguments - all end up in the above message.

The datafile is public, so it's easy to repro the issue:

```
curl -L https://archive.org/download/nycTaxiTripData2013/faredata2013.zip | funzip > datafile
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you encountered the issue if you try this as separate steps? (ie curl to save to file, then funzip)

Comment: @haylem yes, when i just try to download it, curl stop at ~3.2GB...

Comment: @OlegShirokikh are you using 32 bit operating system?

Comment: @haylem - 64bit... I have got couple single-part `.tar.gz` files that are way larger than 8GB uncompressed

Comment: To get all the file, you can use `curl -C  - ...` to restart a partial download to a file (then use unzip).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands you're using can only extract data from the first entry in a ZIP archive; this is mentioned explicitly in the [`funzip` manpage](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/funzip.html):

> *funzip* without a file argument acts as a filter; that is, it assumes that a ZIP archive (or a *gzip*'d(1) file) is being piped into standard input, and it extracts the first member from the archive to stdout.

`faredata2013.zip` contains multiple entries, so you need to use `unzip` to extract them. If you want to extract them to `stdout`, you can use `unzip` with the `-c` option, and add `-q` if you just want the raw contents of all the files in the archive. (`-c` extracts the archive's contents to `stdout`, by default with a header giving each file's name before its contents; `-q` extracts without outputting the file names). You can also use the `-p` option instead of both `-c` and `-q`.

Comment: @Stepen - Thanks, I've read this funzip's docs part.. I've tried above command with `-c` and `-cq` args (for `funzip`) - still the same behavior. Did it work for you? ...Or did you mean these args for `unzip` - I thought that it doesn't support decompression to stdout

Comment: They're supposed to be used with `unzip`, I'll clarify that.

Comment: OK, understood.. `unzip` can write to `stdout` but can't read from it... Is it really the case that it's not possible to decompress piped multi-part files at all...

Comment: Yes, that's one of the limitations of `unzip`; it can extract to `stdout` but can't read an archive from `stdin`. `jar` can process archives from its `stdin` but can't output to `stdout`!